# PyCharm 2.7 + django 1.4.3 + can't import flup.sever.fcgi_fork

Tags: django, pycharm, fastcgi, flup

OS: Windows 7
Django: 1.4.3

**Actions Taken:**

- Upgraded from PyCharm 2.6.3 to PyCharm 2.7
- Opened a project that was working perfectly fine on PyCharm 2.6.3.
- Ran `manage.py run` under PyCharm
- Received an error that flup was not installed (didn't need flup in PyCharm 2.6.3)
- Ran `pip install flup` at the command line

  `C:\>pip install flup`

  Downloading/unpacking flup
  Downloading flup-1.0.3.dev-20110405.tar.gz (57kB): 57kB downloaded
  Running setup.py egg_info for package flup

  Installing collected packages: flup
  Running setup.py install for flup

  `Successfully installed flup`
  Cleaning up...
- Ran `manage.py run` under PyCharm

Received the following error:

```
runnerw.exe C:\Python27\python.exe "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2.7\helpers\pycharm\django_manage.py" runfcgi C:/<location of my project>
Can't import flup.server.fcgi_fork

Process finished with exit code 0
```

**Question:** How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the auto-complete feature for manage.py commands defaults to the less commonly used `runfcgi` under PyCharm 2.7 instead of `runserver`.

Now I have to type `runs`.

Answer (score 0):

fcgi_fork is using in unix like os. If you want to run in windows, just run like below:

```
python manage.py runfcgi thread=4
```